# what's the meaning of number of volumes?

Tags: weed-fs

I deploy one seaweedfs master and one volume server

```
/usr/bin/weed master -ip=10.110.200.149 -port=9333 -mdir=/weed/mdir
/usr/bin/weed volume -ip=10.110.200.149 -dir=/weed/vdir -port=8080 -mserver=10.110.200.149:9333 -max=7
```

When running for several weeks, it show error:

```
curl -X POST http://10.110.200.149:9333/dir/assign
{"error":"No free volumes left!"}
```

I change volumes from 7 to 50(parameter **max**), it solved. But I check the disk size of seaweedfs usage

```
[root@node149 vdir]# ls
1.dat  1.idx  2.dat  2.idx  3.dat  3.idx  4.dat  4.idx  5.dat  5.idx  6.dat  6.idx  7.dat  7.idx
[root@node149 vdir]# du . -hs
14M .
[root@node149 vdir]#
```

It show only 14M disk space usage, so what's the really meaning of number of volumes?

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded any files into the FS. Then the total space used by the files will be what you are seeing as 14M.
If you were expecting to see 50 volumes use 50 times the space allocated for each volume then you are wrong because this space will be used when fully filled with files. 
Before you store any files in your weed-fs, the space used by all volumes should be a low number and it increases as you add more files.